# Can I use only subdomains for my site contents?

Tags: seo, subdomain

I have a domain name `www.site.com`, here for SEO (main keyword) purpose, I would like to use `english.site.com`, is it have any negative impact on SEO? without having content on main domain. (i.e. there is no content on direct `www.site.com` or only just having link to `english.site.com`).

I don't have experience in this case, any one can advice me? am I right or wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search engines consider `www.site.com` and `english.site.com` as two different websites for SEO. Therefore, there is no impact for SEO if you don't use the root domain name for your content.

However, if I were you, I don't only put a link on `www.site.com` to `english.site.com`. If you think doing that for your users, you should apply a 301 redirect from `www.site.com` to `english.site.com` instead.

Comment: thanks for kind information, Please advice me using sub domain name for keyword purpose is it good practice?

Comment: Nowadays, using a keyword in a domain name is not a good pratice anymore. Especially for choosing a domain name, it's better to think "branding" instead.